# svn error E160013: Working copy path 'somedir/somefile' does not exist in repository

Tags: svn, svn-repository, svn-update

I have an svn repository which I was working with for several years. One day I ran `svn update` command on one of my working copies and that is what I've got:

```
shell> svn update
Updating '.':
svn: E160013: Working copy path 'somedir/somefile' does not exist in repository
```

That is what going on in the working directory:

```
shell> svn status
!       .
!       somedir
```

I tried `svn revert -R .`, it yelds a long list of files which already exist and have not been changed, not from `somedir`, but the issue remains.

There were no merges or anything fancy before I started to get this. Just simple regular work, commits to trunk.

What is this and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was an issue of a particular working copy (probably some files in `.svn` directory were corrupted, I didn't check).

I just created another working copy and the problem was gone.